# How come both isset() and empty() use the same opcode?

Tags: php

If both `isset()` and `empty()` generate the exact same `ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ` opcode, how can the PHP VM tell the difference between the two?

This code:

```
empty($a['b']);
isset($a['b']);
```

produces the following opcodes:

```
ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ $a, b -> TMP_VAR 0
FREE TMP_VAR 0

ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ $a, b -> TMP_VAR 1
FREE TMP_VAR 1
```

---

Another test:

```
if (empty($a['b'])) {
    echo 'abc';
}

if (isset($a['b'])) {
    echo 'abc';
}
```

This produces:

```
ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ $a, b -> TMP_VAR 0
JMPZ TMP_VAR 0, &(BC4E00+4)
ECHO abc
JMP &(BC4E00+4)

ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ $a, b -> TMP_VAR 1
JMPZ TMP_VAR 1, &(BC4FE0+8)
ECHO abc
JMP &(BC4FE0+8)
```

Comment: How come did you get at this level lol

Comment: This could be the result of some optimization. You are not using the return value. Try something more complex like an `if (…)`.

Comment: I also tried `var_dump()` on the result of both functions to see if somehow `isset()` now does exactly what `empty()` does, but no, one result was `true`, another was `false`, both with identical opcodes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever tool you were using to create that opcode dump, it only told you half the truth: It forgot to mention that PHP is passing a constant to that opcode depending on which language construct was used. Those constants are `ZEND_ISEMPTY` for `empty` and `ZEND_ISSET` for `isset`.

You can find the invocations [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#984) and [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#993). (And [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_compile.c#4445) the type is put into the `extended_value` of the opcode.)

If you look at the [full opcodes](http://codepad.viper-7.com/THiFYG), you'll see those constants as `1` (`ZEND_ISSET = (1<<0)`) and `2` (`ZEND_ISEMPTY = (1<<1)`) in the `ext` column.

Answer (score 4):

How did you get those opcodes?

I ran your code snippet using "[Bytekit](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/871-bytekit-cli.html)", and got the following output:

```
Function:           main
Number of oplines:  5
Compiled variables: !0 = $a

  line  #     opcode                           result  operands
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3     0     ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ                  ~0      !0, 'b'
        1     FREE                                     ~0
  4     2     ISSET_DIM_OBJ                    ~1      !0, 'b'
        3     FREE                                     ~1
  6     4     RETURN                                   1
```

So, in this case, there is a difference in opcodes. 
Only thing is, I cannot seem to find 'my' opcodes on the official PHP website. This kind of puzzles me, because bytekit has proven to be an excellent tool so far.

I'll look into that, but in the meantime, I thought, you might find my current output of any value.

By the way, I am PHP running 5.3.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: It must be because of the PHP version. I'm using PHP 5.3.4.